# K thermocouple readings bad probe or circuit?

Tags: amplifier, analog, thermocouple

I recently put together this circuit to read a K thermocouple.  It takes the probes reading and converts it into an analog voltage.
[image: thermocouple reading]
The design came from:
[image: design]

I am getting poor readings from the circuit though.  Here is a graph of a comparison of the sensor's readings with the real temperature of a system.
I almost have a 1 to 1 slope with my readings versus the actual temperature which is good.  But I am reading about 14C lower than I should be..

[image: graph]

This is not the most troubling issue to me though.  The ADC readouts are oscillating with a consistent frequency.  For example here is an image of the readings in real time.  Sample frequency was 1s and readings are in Celcius.  I was ramping up the temperature of a vessel containing oil using a hot plate.
[image: oscillations]

[image: footprint]

[sensor used](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QRF4XPG)
Does anyone know what could be leading to these issues?

Comment: How does your PCB design looks like? Do you have bypass caps for the reference and op-amp chips? When you sample once per second, how precise it is? Can that wiggling be sub-sampled 50 or 60 Hz mains voltage hum?

Comment: 1. Are you using proper thermocouple compensating cable or is there a risk that you have additional thermocouple joints in your system? 2. Many commercial temperature controllers offer 50 Hz or 60 Hz mains filtering. This means they sample at an odd number of mains half cycles and averaging these values eliminates the oscillation caused by mains interference.

Comment: @Justme I have added the pcb layout.  But I am not sure what you mean about subsampling?  Should I increase sampling frequency to 60Hz.  I am using ESP32 ADC.

Comment: @Transistor  I am not sure why mains would matter my PCB is powered by 5VDC.  Will attempt to operate this pcb off a battery to verify

Comment: You've got an amplifier with a grain of -246. Any pickup from mains writing in the building will be amplified too - especially the high currents in the nearby hotplate.

Comment: The ESP32 adc is not known to be a particularly good one. I'd suggest using an external adc for better eprformance. A 24bit sigma-delta type with a PGA might be more suitable to measure the thermocouple directly and bypass the need for analog amplification. Or there's the Maxim chips specifically for this purpose.
 It looks like you have used a 4 layer pcb, but you power need ateention in regarss to bypass capacitors. You also want to consider layout, ground plane and chassis earth layout. Chassis earth really shouldn't be meandering amongst your analog circuitry.

Comment: @Kartman I agree that ESP adc is not the best.  But I have never seen it this bad.  I will move the Chasis circuitry for the next board.  But it is not connected to anything during this testing so no chance of interference.  I am also not sure how to compensate the cable or if it is.

Comment: nail down where the problem is. Realise the thermocouple is acting as an antenna and could easily be picking up interference. In your circuit it looks like the thermocouple is floating above 0V due to the cold junction compensation which makes the situation more difficult as you cannot ground one side of the thermocouple. You might want to rethink your circuitry.

Comment: @Kartman I moved to several different locations as well as turned off a lot of surrounding electronics.  These standing waves went away!  I am dumfounded, but still getting readings to low as indicated by the graph.  Also I have ordered a better thermocouple to eliminate this possibility

Comment: https://peaksensors.co.uk/what-is/compensating-cable/#:~:text=Compensating%20cable%20is%20a%20type,cheaper%20alloys%20than%20extension%20cable.

Comment: Your hot-plate - is it a bang-bang controller? Check your circuit using a battery. [Much related to this earlier question by the OP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/575966/why-is-this-thermocouple-amplifier-with-analog-output-circuit-not-working)

Comment: How does the 14C error compare with the expected offset voltages around the opamp?

Comment: @Andyaka this is the same circuit minus the voltage divider.  Now it responds to temperature with a near 1 to 1 ratio, before it didn't even work I was overworking the amp.

Comment: @user_1818839 let me check